# How to create a dynamic url with wordpress userid or username?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to achieve something that would create a URL of the following structure

```
https://example.com/profile/<username>/notification
```

I want to insert this URL in another plugin that would create a navigation button with this dynamic link.

I used this code:

```
<?php 


include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php');

global $wpdb;

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

$c = $current_user->ID;

 ?>

       <option value="<?php echo ‘../profile/'.$c.'/notifications' ?>" <?php selected(myplugin::getSetting('NavigationTabBarProfile'), ‘../profile/'.$c.'/notifications' ) ?>><?php echo "My Notif" ?></option>
```

But the url always displays the userid of the admin that is logged into wp-admin and not the current user who is clicking the link. Even if I visit the link in private/incognito mode, it still fetches the userid of the last logged in admin.

I have been working on this for hours now, any help would be greatly appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `get_site_url()` wordpress function ?

```php
value="<?php echo get_site_url() . '/profile/' . $c . '/notifications'; ?>"
```

(Sorry I can't comment because my reputation is under 50...)

EDIT : Here is my result when debugging `wp_get_current_user()`

[image]

To do a debug like that I write this line in first line of my template page :

```
wp_die( var_dump( wp_get_current_user() ) );
```

You can try to put this line on your first page (the one called on plugins' wordpress hook) to see what happend. If the user is different, it means that the current user has been changed on script.

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'test_user' );

function test_user() {
    wp_die( var_dump( wp_get_current_user() ) );
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
The url structure is working fine, only the USERID ($c) is not getting dynamically updated to the current loggedin user.

Comment: And `get_currentuserinfo()` display non admin info ? Did you try `wp_get_current_user()` instead of the glob var `$current_user` ?

Comment: yes I tried. It still populates the userid of the admin instead of the user that logged in and clicked the link.

Comment: mmmh I'm sorry but when I try at home, it works correctly :/ Are you sure that you're registered with another user ? If you can access to the admin panel, it means that you're still the admin. Try to change the url to access your admin panel and see if you have an error saying it's not possible to display this page. If yes, it means that you're indeed connected with another account. If you have a connection form, it means that you're not connected at all. If you see the admin panel, you're still connected as an admin.

Comment: I tried from another device, not logged into any account, still the USER ID is the admin I account that is logged in by me.

Comment: https://example.com/profile/23/notification is the URL I get from any device even when the user is not logged in.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you what I get when I debug `wp_get_current_user()`, your result is kind of strange... Maybe the wordpress current user is changed in another script. (try to debug it in your plugin first page for example on init hook to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses "me" permalink... So the answer without any unnecessary code would be
https://example.com/profile/me/notification

Comment: This is not an answer. Please read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)